# Rest-Client usage ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms

I have a ruby controller class with a def create. I am using rest client to get to a web page such as google. basically this is my code ignore the other details related to creating since.

```
 def create
  RestClient.get 'http://google.com'
  @smsclass = Smsclass.new(params[:smsclass])

  respond_to do |format|
   if @smsclass.save
     format.html { redirect_to RestClient.get 'http://google.com'}
     format.html { redirect_to @smsclass, :notice => 'Smsclass was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :json => @smsclass, :status => :created, :location => @smsclass }
   else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
     format.json { render :json => @smsclass.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
```

end

I have required rest client. Let me know whats wrong. Thakn You.

Comment: to me this looks fishy !!. Is there something you missed to mention in the question ?

Comment: I dont think so. however. if i use this as charlysisto suggested if i just use redirect-to it works. My end problem is to send post requests using rest-client. hence i wanted to first have the get working. I the post as RestClient.post 'http://services.yyy.com/SMS/TXT/?wsvKey=_7iutVlqdDcyfjffptZ1', :from => 'yyy', :nested => { :to => '07980760812' } but this doesnt work. it says no data recieved.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to` follows an url not the 'result' of that url.

Just do `format.html { redirect_to 'http://google.com'}` if you want it to go on google.

Comment: I dont think so. however. if i use this as charlysisto suggested if i just use redirect-to it works. My end problem is to send post requests using rest-client. hence i wanted to first have the get working. I the post as RestClient.post 'services.yyy.com/SMS/TXT/?wsvKey=_7iutVlqdDcyfjffptZ1';, :from => 'yyy', :nested => { :to => '07980760812' } but this doesnt work. it says no data recieved.